# Combining 2 javascript scripts

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a colorful map of Turkey like in this picture in full width html page. The main point is make user select colors for each city.

At the end of the day, I want to have a scene like this: 
[image: final picture]

In order to do that, I have to combine 2 scripts below. But I couldn't find a proper way to do it.

The first one is the map:
Here is the adress of my [repository](https://github.com/domajor7th/map).

Second one is the colorpicker: [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/)

I want to use colorpicker for each city like that: (the information could be in a different div below)
[image: colorpicker_usage]

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? The question is way too broad in its current form.

Comment: at first step, in js color, you have to add the class , but since the cities are created by js i can't add class for changing color. so im stuck, i need some fresh ideas about how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the contents of 2 Javascript file into 1 file then simply create a new e.g. mapcolor.js and copy content of the map file into this file then copy content of the colorpicker file at the end of this file.

If you instead want to Load both these javascript files into your page then you can do like so in the  of your html page:

```
<html>
   <title>İnteraktif Türkiye Haritası</title>
   <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jscolor.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- Your body elements goes here... -->
   </body>
</html>
```

If not, then please share a bit more information on what you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building an image map out of whatever map it is you want the end user to color. There are tons of image mappers online for free that you can use to accomplish that section of the task, it will give you something along the lines of this:

```
<div class="mapContainer">
  <img id="bottle_map" src="../images/bottle.jpg" usemap="#bottle_map">
  <map name="bottle_map">
    <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="3,6,258,31" href="#" title="Saranac Legacy IPA">
    <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="279,5,336,32" href="#" title="four generations">
    <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="2,37,425,64" href="#" title="four generations">
    <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="1,69,386,95" href="#" title="four generations">
    <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="243,121,444,142" href="#" title="Matt Brewing Company">
    <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="4,143,186,163" href="#" title="Matt Brewing Company">
    <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="194,144,400,163" href="#" title="Our (great) grandfather">
    <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="3,163,252,187" href="#" title="Our (great) grandfather">
    <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="295,166,419,185" href="#" title="it's still family">
    <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="3,189,363,209" href="#" title="it's still family">
  </map>
  <canvas class="ctxLight" id="canvMap"></canvas>
</div>
```

The Div and the canvas tags should be added by you after whatever website you use to make the map gives you all the area tags and such.

From there you can use HTML5's canvasing feature to overlay shapes and such of whatever color/opacity you want over the maps

```
$(function() {
  var ctx;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  var area;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

  function calcDimension (obj) {
    var dimension = []
    position = obj.attr('coords').split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if (i < 2)
        dimension[i] = parseInt(position[i], 10);
      else
        dimension[i] = Math.abs(position[i -2] - position[i]);
    }
    return dimension
  }

  $('.mapContainer').css( {
    "position": "relative",
    "display": "inline-block"
  } );
  $('.imgLight').css( {
    "position": "absolute",   // necessery styling for                                                                                                                                                                                       
    "z-index": "1"            // layering image and canvas                                                                                                                                                                                   
  } );
  $('.ctxLight').css( {                                                                                                                                                                            
    "position": "relative",                                                                                                                                                         
    "z-index": "2",
    "pointerEvents": "none"
  } );

  ctx = document.getElementById('canvMap').getContext('2d');
  $('#canvMap').attr('width', $('#bottle_map').width());
  $('#canvMap').attr('height', $('#bottle_map').height());

  $('map > area').click(function() {
    area = calcDimension($(this));
    ctx.clearRect(area[0],area[1],area[2],area[3]); //prevents img stacking
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)"; //last number is opacity
    ctx.fillRect(area[0],area[1],area[2],area[3]);
  } );
} );
```

Basically, when an area is clicked on the image map, the canvas will draw over the area that was clicked.

What I just gave you will not clear the coloring away when clicked again. I am sure you can come up with some logic as to how you want that to work. All that's needed to clear it is to call:

```
ctx.clearRect(x1, y1, w, h);
```

The calcDimension function I gave you will return those 4 numbers for you so you only have to pass it a jQuery obj containing the area the user clicked to do so.

You can use the color picking script you have listed in your question to generate the hex color values and then convert those to standars 0-255 rgb values the the canvasing engine can interpret.